# How to fix price error for a product in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am trying to fix this product listing: http://shop.crystalvine.com/salt/blueberrysalt-c.html

You see in the dropdown there is an option for "refill" which is supposed to say $10.95 but says $45.95

When I log into Magento and click on Catalog --> Manage Products

There are f different listings for this product, differentiated by size/price. I try to edit the price by clicking "edit" on the product and under the price option on the left I edit the price and save.

But doing that to the products does not change the price on the live site when I edit the price for them.

Am I doing something wrong there? How do I change the price?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the right product? Maybe someone was careless and made a duplicate. Make sure the product you're editing is the right one that's associated with that configurable product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you need to edit the price of an existing configurable product.

You're going to need to change the price in two places (I think).

First off, when you create a configurable product with 'associated products' each associated product is a simple product in itself. You should search for the refill product and edit the price in there as you would any other product. Then you will need to edit your configurable product, navigate to the associated products tab and edit the difference in price there (so $-14.00).

Should do it.

EDIT: This is the section you want. It's in the associated products tab of your configurable product and allows you set price differences for each product.

[image: Associated Products]